# Make a speaker vibrate at a defined frequency in Ubuntu Linux, with GNU Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, gnu, gnu-assembler, low-level

**I am new to assembly language**

Our computer makes sound all the time (mp3, wav, mp4, ogg, etc).

How could I directly communicate to a speaker with assembly language? In C, you can use "Beep()" and pass duration in milliseconds and hertz of the sound to the speaker. How could I do this in GNU assembly language?

My Computer Specs:
Dell Optiplex 960;
Ubuntu 23.04 LTS
x86-64 architecture.

Could somebody leave and example of how this could be done, I.E. pasting some source code?
Leaving comments on relatively what each instruction is doing would also be very helpful.

I have tried to find some tutorials, but am kind of lost. Most tutorials that were in NASM (Not GNU like I use), would use the systems default sound, I.E. the bell sound on windows, or the notification sound on Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you trying to use the PC-speaker on a PC-compatible (which is often not hooked up to anything in modern desktops).  Or the regular speakers via the sound card, e.g. via ALSA, generating PCM samples yourself for a sine wave?

Comment: My Arch GNU/Linux system doesn't have a `Beep()` function.  `man -a Beep` only shows the ncurses `void beep(void)` (lower case) which just outputs the terminal bell character, no frequency arg.  There's certainly no ISO C standard `Beep(int)` or `double` function, so I have no idea what Beep() function you're talking about.

Comment: If you have a speaker than you can talk to with `beep` (you often have to install it separately), then the info in [syscall to produce sound under linux?](https://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=98.0) (best discussion at the bottom) should point you in the right direction. The nasm listing (missing a few label `':'`), otherwise contains what is needed to reach the hardware speaker. To test a short beep, you can use `beep -f 5000 -l 50 -r 2` if you have it installed (and have a hardware speaker)

Comment: Additionally, after you write code to access the speaker and compile/link it -- on most (if not all) systems, only the root user will have direct access to the speaker hardware. To avoid running as root directly, you can make your executable Set UID/GID (as noted in the initial comments shown in the listing provided in the link in my comment above)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: A setuid-root binary around forever might be more of a vulnerability than manual `sudo`, if there are any buffer overflows or other vulnerabilities in it. (Written by a novice in assembly as a learning exercise is *not* a recipe for hardened software; if you don't include a special `.note` section in every asm source file, your process will even end up with an executable stack, making traditional code-injection attacks possible).  The one saving grace here is that the input is hopefully just a single number, but if you do anything with it, beware of integer overflows...

Comment: If you want to use it regularly, not just try it while getting it working to see how it's done, then yeah, SUID root or SGID to a group that can write the relevant device is a good idea, once you add some input sanity checking.

Comment: You can use libevdev or directly the evdev interface (see [this](https://gist.github.com/zed/9af4ebc7136348721677a35d7fd8cc84)). You can also set ioperm and directly access ports 0x61 and 0x43/42 (see [this](https://wiki.osdev.org/PC_Speaker)). For the latter, you probably need to read about the PIT, its base frequency, and the 8042 controller to really understand what you are doing. Please note that assembly is not required for this task unless you want to use the IO ports for some reason.

Comment: @PeterCordes - agreed. set uid/gid is not a secure way to go. You certainly would not want to leave that test executable lying around with the permissions set as such. `sudo` is the better way to go.

Answer (score 3):

***Update:** According to the online service manual for the Dell Optiplex 960, the internal speaker is an optional device. Therefore, your computer might not have an internal speaker connected and the comments to the question and this answer about using the PC speaker interface will not help much. This answer mainly explains about using the internal speaker, but has a few remarks on PCM audio at the end.*

As I have been maintaining the common Linux beep utility https://github.com/spkr-beep/beep for a few years, I would recommend to use the proper API for the PC speaker on Linux without the need for privileged access.

This amounts to a program which does

- `open(2)` the well-known device file `/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr` and save the file descriptor if successful, abort the program otherwise
- prepare a `struct input_event` (defined in `linux/input.h`) with `e.type = EV_SND`, `e.code = SND_TONE`, `e.value = frequency_in_Hz` (a frequency of `0` will silence the PC speaker) (can be done statically)
- `write(2)` that 24 byte struct to the file descriptor
- eventually `close(2)` the file descriptor

So basically, you just need to write a program which writes a few bytes into a file.

If you want your program to start a tone, then wait, and then stop that tone, your program also needs to wait for a defined time. The `nanosleep(2)` syscall with a `struct timespec` from `time.h` can help you there.

This leaves you with just needing to figure out how to execute the syscalls `open(2)`, `write(2)` and `close(2)`. OK, the `close(2)` is not really needed if you `exit(2)` afterwards anyway, but `nanosleep(2)` is probably needed as well.

Any Linux "hello world" program in assembly should be a good starting point: It will already have implemented `write(2)` and `exit(2)`, and that should be a good place to start from when adding the other syscalls.

Starting with a simple hello world program like [https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/gasexamples/](https://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/gasexamples/) (first hit in search engine for "linux gnu assembly hello world") with some information from https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/ (first hit in search engine for "x86-64 abi") with a few of my own adornments (`.size`, `foo_size = . - foo`, `.balign` and comments, and `.global` for debugging) gives the following program which starts a beep. Stopping the beep is left as an exercise to the reader, or for running `beep` on the shell.

```
# gas-beep.s - do a PC speaker beep with GNU assembler for Linux x86-64

    .global _start
    .text
    .global main_program
main_program:
_start:
    # open(speaker_device, O_WRONLY)
    mov $2, %rax        # sys_open
    mov $speaker_device, %rdi   # filename = speaker_device
    mov $1, %rsi        # flags = O_WRONLY
    xor %rdx, %rdx      # mode = 0
    syscall

    cmp $0, %rax
    jl  error_exit_open

    mov %rax, fd

    # write(fd, &beepcmd_on, sizeof(beepcmd_on))
    mov $1, %rax        # sys_write
    mov fd, %rdi        # fd = fd
    mov $beepcmd_on, %rsi   # buf = beepcmd_on
    mov $beepcmd_on_size, %rdx  # count = sizeof(beepcmd_on)
    syscall

# TODO: nanosleep(2) with a struct timeval aka two .quad values
# TODO: turn off sound using write(2) (beepcmd_off with frequency 0)
# TODO: print a few enlightening words to stdout with write(2)

    # close(fd)
    mov $3, %rax        # sys_close
    mov fd, %rdi        # fd = fd
    syscall

    # exit(0)
    mov $60, %rax       # sys_exit
    xor %rdi, %rdi      # error_code = 0
    syscall

error_exit_open:
    # write(1, errmsg_open, sizeof(errmsg_open))
    mov $1, %rax        # sys_write
    mov $2, %rdi        # fd = STDERR_FILENO
    mov $errmsg_open, %rsi  # buf = errmsg_open
    mov $errmsg_open_size, %rdx # count = sizeof(errmsg_open)
    syscall

    # exit(2)
    mov $60, %rax       # sys_exit
    xor $2, %rdi        # error_code = 2
    syscall

    .size   main_program, . - main_program

    .balign 8
    .global beepcmd_on
    # struct input_event {.type=EV_SND, .code=SND_TONE, .value=880}
beepcmd_on:
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .short  0x12            # .type = EV_SND
    .short  0x02            # .code = SND_TONE
    .int    880         # .value = frequency
beepcmd_on_size = . - beepcmd_on    # required for write(2)
    .size   beepcmd_on, beepcmd_on_size

    .global speaker_device
speaker_device:
    .asciz  "/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr"
    .size   speaker_device, . - speaker_device

    .global errmsg_open
errmsg_open:
    .ascii  "Error: Could not open(2) the device.\n"
errmsg_open_size = . - errmsg_open  # required for write(2)
    .size   errmsg_open, errmsg_open_size

    .bss

    .global fd
    .lcomm  fd, 8           # uninitialized file descriptor variable
```

To make building this and understanding it easier, use the following `GNUmakefile` which builds you a symbol list, a map file, a disassembled view, etc. of the whole program:

```
.PHONY: all
all: all-local

TARGETS += gas-beep.lss
%.lss: %
    objdump -h -S $< > $@

TARGETS += gas-beep.syms
%.syms: %
    objdump --syms $< > $@

TARGETS += gas-beep.nm
%.nm: %
    nm $< > $@

TARGETS += gas-beep.map
%.map: %

TARGETS += gas-beep
gas-beep: gas-beep.o
    ld -g -Map=gas-beep.map -o $@ $^

TARGETS += gas-beep.lst
%.lst: %.o

TARGETS += gas-beep.stripped
%.stripped: %
    strip -s -o $@ $<

TARGETS += gas-beep.readelf-a
%.readelf-a: %
    readelf -a $< > $@

%.o: %.s
    gcc -Wall -Werror -g -Wa,-adhlns=$*.lst -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY: all-local
all-local: $(TARGETS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.{lss,lst,map,nm,o,readelf-a,stripped,syms} gas-beep
```

Note that you might need to explicitly install and load the `pcspkr.ko` kernel module, and make sure your computer actually has a physical PC speaker connected (speaker or piezo buzzer). Installing your operating system's `beep` package could save you some manual sysadmin work.

So much for the PC speaker.

If you want to produce sound via PCM audio instead of using the PC speaker, the API will probably be a lot more complex than just writing a few bytes to a file. Twentry years ago, preparing a simple memory buffer for PCM audio with a square wave to `write(2)` to an `open(2)`ed PCM audio device `/dev/dsp` was of comparable complexity. These days however, even just finding a device to open is a lot more complex, and we are not even talking about buffers running out and refilling buffers, and there is more than one PCM sound API.